# Error with mysql permissions. Involving SELECT command

Tags: c#, mysql

When I try to click a button on my app (VS 2017) that uses mysql it gives me this error :

> 'SELECT command denied to user 'xx_sorci'@'xx-xx-xxx-x8.try.xx.com' for table 'proc''

Something weird is my table name is called `users` not `proc`.

That could be a problem. Also this uses stored procedures so that could also help.

**Visual studio code:**

```cs
using (MySqlConnection mysqlCon = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))

    {
Some of the code https://pastebin.com/raw/Jmcn3mfh

        mysqlCon.Open();
        MySqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new MySqlDataAdapter("BookSearchByValue", mysqlCon);
        sqlDa.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlDa.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("_SearchValue", txtSearch.Text);
        DataTable dtblBook = new DataTable();
        sqlDa.Fill(dtblBook);
        dgvBook.DataSource = dtblBook;
        dgvBook.Columns[0].Visible = false;
    }
```

**Procedure:**

```
PROCEDURE `BookSearchByValue`
    (
        _SearchValue VARCHAR(45)
    )
        BEGIN
            SELECT * FROM login
            WHERE Username LIKE CONCAT('%' +_SearchValue+'%') 
            || Password LIKE CONCAT('%' +_SearchValue+'%');
        END
```

**EDIT:** Added this `Use Procedure Bodies = false;` to the con string and it worked.

Comment: try doing your SQL command in SSMS first before putting into your code.

Comment: Try connecting the MySqL from workbench with the same user, does it give the same error?

Comment: Doesn't give the same error. Also I bought this from interserver if that helps.

Comment: Are you able to connect successfully from workbench? Can you share the code which is throwing error?

Comment: Trigger on the table?

Comment: I'm connecting just fine to mysql workbench. In mysql workbench I can do the select command. Could be something with the table or procedures.

Comment: Please do not post external links (or at least without code samples) as it could be broken in the future and it won't help others that could have the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you're using Connector/NET (aka MySql.Data). (Full exception details would help us; please include them next time: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/.)

This sounds like a variant of [MySQL Bug 52294](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=52294) where Connector/NET needs the ability to read the `mysql.proc` table in order to execute a stored procedure. There are two possible solutions:

1. Set `CheckParameters=False` in your connection string. This will disable retrieval of stored procedure metadata (avoiding the error), but may lead to harder-to-debug problems calling other stored procedures if you don't get the order and type of parameters exactly right. (Connector/NET can no longer map them for you using the metadata.)
2. Switch to a different ADO.NET MySQL library that doesn't have this bug: [MySqlConnector](https://mysqlconnector.net/) on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/). It's highly compatible with Connector/NET, performs faster, and fixes a lot of [known issues](https://mysqlconnector.net/tutorials/migrating-from-connector-net/#fixed-bugs).